# Which preposition do I use after the verb "negotiate"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Do I have to use the preposition *about* or *for* after *negotiate*.For example:

> We will negotiate with the company **about**/**for** a better deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sentence is correct.

> **We will negotiate with the company for/ about a better deal**

You can use either **for** or **about** in your sentence

Here is the link.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/negotiate

Answer (score 4):

It is not idiomatic say "negotiate *for/about*" just as it would be incorrect to say "discuss *for...*"

You can discuss a topic with someone. You can negotiate a deal with someone.

Your sentence should be:

> We will negotiate a better deal with the company.

Comment: Does you sentence mean that we will try to get a better deal or we thnk that we will get it?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I don't think anybody would enter into negotiations unless they were hopeful of getting a better deal. I would say that optimism is tacit in the sentence. Negotiation is a process where different opinions/suggestions are discussed. There is no guarantee of outcome suggested by the sentence. If you wanted to imply that you were *less* optimistic, you could say "we will *try* to negotiate a better deal".

Comment: What do you think of the sentence "We will negotiate with the company for a better deal? Does that sound ok?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I think it is wrong. See the correct structure in my answer.

Comment: I am confused. Because in of the answers to my question there is an example sentence where my example is totally valid. Could you check it out please?

Answer (score 3):

**negotiate** takes direct objects:

We will negotiate with the company about/for a better deal.

should be:

**We will negotiate a better deal** with the company.

That is the most idiomatic.

Any dictionary will tell you that so I am not bothering to cite one.

It is possible to say: for a better deal but in written form that is not the best choice.

Comment: ‘The trade unions should make this as part of their bargaining when negotiating for conditions of service with employers.’ This example is from the Oxford Dictionary. Is this sentence wrong?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Of course it isn't wrong. It's also **not a verb**: it's a gerund [noun]. |make this part of their bargaining|, right?  Anyway, that is a noun. Learning English is tough.  learning=noun

Comment: part of or a part of, but not: make this as part of, you miscopied.

Comment: But what about this one from the same dictionary "We have been negotiating for more pay",?

Comment: If something is in an authoritative dictionary like an Oxford Dictionary, there is no need to ask about it.

Comment: Just wanted to know your opinion

Comment: The better question is: Why is the difference between "negotiate something" AND "negotiate for something". Right? You could have checked more dictionaries first and showed us that you had.

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with Lambie and Astralbee.

> Which preposition do I use after the verb “negotiate”?

That depends on the context, I will explain.

> Do I have to use the preposition *about* or *for* after negotiate? For example: . . .

No, you don't have to use those two all the time.

For your example sentence

> We will negotiate with the company about/for a better deal.

I feel the best choice would be what Lambie and Astralbee suggested: *"We will negotiate a better deal with the company."* Here are a few related examples:

- Retailers should be allowed to negotiate prices directly **with** producers (Cambridge).
- The government has refused to negotiate **with** the terrorists (Cambridge).
- I've managed to negotiate a five percent pay increase **with** my boss (Cambridge).
- We want to negotiate a settlement that is fair to both sides (Cambridge).

Note how the focus in these examples are on the parties involved. Now let's look at the use of **"for"**:

- We have been negotiating **for** more pay (Oxford Learners Dictionary).
- He spent ages negotiating **for** a pay increase, only to resign from his job soon after he'd received it (Cambridge).
- He is negotiating **for** higher royalties from the record company (Cambridge).
- I'm negotiating **for** a new contract (Cambridge).
- His publishing house had just begun negotiating **for** her next books (Collins).
- Coast Mountain Bus Company have delivered an overwhelming 99 percent strike mandate, after negotiations **for** a new collective agreement broke off (Newswire Cision).
- The UAW [United Automobile Workers' union] is negotiating **for** higher wages, greater job security, and a path for temporary workers to seniority (Gmauthority).

Note how in all these examples, the focus is on what you are negotiating for and not on the parties. Also note the frequent use of "negotiating".

To sum up, in your example sentence, if you want to focus on the "deal", then you can say

> "We will negotiate for a better deal" or "We will be negotiating for a better deal."

and if you want to focus on the party you are negotiating with, then say what Lambie and Astralbee suggested

> "We will negotiate a better deal with the company."

The use of "about" as a proposition is more rare than the use of "for".

---

Edit: As Jason Bassford pointed out in the comments, the prepositions *"for"* and *"about"* become more usable in your example sentence when we change the form to "negotiation" (noun), and if we rephrase the sentence just a bit.

*"(1) Our negotiations with the company are **for** a better deal. 
(2) Our negotiations with the company are **about getting** a better deal."*

Comment: I would say that negotiate a better deal focuses on the better deal.

Comment: Note that if you use the noun *negotiation*, then you can use the prepositions—and *about* becomes much more common. (1) *Our **negotiations** with the company are **for** a better deal.* (2) *Our **negotiations** with the company are **about getting** a better deal.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah yes that is why I couldn't find much use of "about"; I didn't look for it with negotiations. Can I edit my answer to incorporate your comment with credit?

Comment: @AIQ Be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

No, *about* and *for* are not the **only** prepositions you can use after the word *negotiate*.

For example, you can:

> negotiate with someone/a view to (as you illustrate)
>   negotiate after lunch
>   negotiate in good time
>   negotiate before supper
>   negotiate around an issue 
>   negotiate on common ground

and so on.

It all depends on the context.